# Unable to automatically save a file after reading it in. c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I am attempting to create a note taking application (first Windows Forms application). So far I have managed to read a .txt file into a RichTextBox. I am trying to make the program create and save the .txt file containing the contents of the .txt file that was read in read in.   So when the user adds text from a file it creates a new file in a notes folders that is in the root directory of application.  Please see my code below.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Cheers

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //read in a .txt file
        OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
        richTextBox1.LoadFile(op.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
        this.Text = op.FileName;

        string fileName = op.FileName;

        //create new .txt file contaning module notes
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("\\"+fileName);
        file.WriteLine(fileName);
        file.Close();
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem? What error (if any) are you getting?

Comment: Apologies!  It's not actually creating a new .txt file.    There is no error...

Comment: @JonnyAppleseed, if it turns out you don't actually have a question after all, it's helpful to delete it

Comment: This isn't the root directory of the application. You need a real fully qualified path. new System.IO.StreamWriter("\\"+fileName);

Comment: Your fileName variable in this example has the entire path in it also, so you need to do a little more with that. Stick a breakpoint on there and you can see the path and name it tries to create. It does throw an exception when I do this, so I'm not sure why you dont see one.

Answer (score 1):

Tested and working

```
 //read in a .txt file
            OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                richTextBox1.LoadFile(op.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
            this.Text = op.FileName;

            string fileName = Path.Combine(Application.CommonAppDataPath, Path.GetFileName(op.FileName));
            File.WriteAllText(fileName, "test");
```

Answer (score 0):

- wrap your streams, files (anything that implements IDisposable) in a using block:

`using(var myfile = File. CreateText(path) )  {
  myfile.WriteLine("hi");
}`

- it's not creating a file because the path is wrong